# Resizing an ImageIcon

Tags: java, image, image-resizing

I am trying to resize my image to fit my java screen but i keep getting this error
"Syntax error on token ";", , expected  "

There isnt much to the code either:

```
import java.awt.Image;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;

public class Images 
{
    ImageIcon welcomeImage = new ImageIcon("WelcomeImage.PNG");
    Image image = welcomeImage.getImage();
    Image newImage = image.getScaledInstance(750, 500, java.awt.Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);//The error appears on this line
    welcomeImage = new ImageIcon(newImage);
    
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put your code in a method, not directly in the class definition.

Try this for instance:

```
import java.awt.Image;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;

public class Images 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ImageIcon welcomeImage = new ImageIcon("WelcomeImage.PNG");
        Image image = welcomeImage.getImage();
        Image newImage = image.getScaledInstance(750, 500, java.awt.Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);//The error appears on this line
        welcomeImage = new ImageIcon(newImage);
    }
}
```